# How to use initialize a bytes array with abi data?

Tags: solidity, abi, bytes, abiencoderv2

To initialize a bytes array with the bool value `True` encoded as ABI data, I'm attempting to do it like this:

```js
bytes memory arr = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001';
```

I can't find anything online on how to do it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching the web on how to initialie a bytes array with abi data and found next to nothing. After banging my head against the desk for a couple hours, I've figured out how to properly initialize a bytes array with abi data.

I found that the correct way is like this:

```js
bytes memory arr = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01';
```

To convert anything to abi data and initialize any bytes array on solidity with the result, install the 'eth-abi' python package and run the encode_abi function, like so:

```
$ pip3 install eth-abi
$ python3
>>> encode_abi(['bool','string','string'], [True,'foo','bar'])
>>> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03foo\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03bar\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I'm using https://studio.ethereum.org/ to test this, my contract is the following:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;
contract HelloWorld {

    string public message;

    constructor(string memory initMessage) public {
        message = initMessage;
    }

    function update(string memory) public {

        bytes memory messageB = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03foo\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03bar\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00';

        bool result;
        string memory result1;
        string memory result2;

        (result,result1,result2) = abi.decode(messageB,(bool,string,string));

        //if((keccak256(abi.encodePacked(("bar"))) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked((result))) )){        
        if(result == true){
           message = result1;
        }else{
           message = result2; 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a bytes array with an hex string, like this:

```
bytes memory arr = hex'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001';
```

See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#hexadecimal-literals